# What is the degree of the following map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $a \notin S^1$, $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, be given by $z \mapsto \frac{z-a}{|z-a|}$. What is the degree of $f$?

Where by degree we mean under the usual definition [here](https://www.merry.io/algebraic-topology-i-lecture-notes/5-the-fundamental-group-of-the-circle-and-pushouts)
or general case  [here](https://www.merry.io/algebraic-topology-i-lecture-notes/15-the-degree) .

---

My current thoughts are usuing the definition that it is the value of the unique lift, when $f$ is idenitfied with $\hat{f}:I \rightarrow S^1$, $\hat{f}(1)=\deg f$. But this requires me to explicitly construct a lift of the map

$$ \hat{f}:I \rightarrow S^1, s \mapsto \frac{e^{2 \pi i s} - a }{ |e^{2 \pi i s} - a | }.$$
which seems plausible but messy. I would be interested for an elegant proof.

Comment: Have you thought about using local degree?

Comment: what is local degree? Sorry I have been only working with basic definitions. Some reference would help a lot.

Comment: see page 136 of http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf

Comment: Do you know that homotopic maps have the same degree?

Comment: Another hint: consider the case $\lvert a\rvert<1$ and the case $\lvert a \rvert>1$ separately.

Comment: Yes, homoptic maps being of same degree follows from homotopy axiom. So: If $|a|<1$,  then we can work on the homotopy $z-ta/|z-ta|$, if $|a|>1$, then we can use $tz-a/|tz-a|$. Is this what you mean? So the degree of for $|a|<1$ is $1$ and $|a|>1$ is $0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yup that's perfect! By the way, the intuition herr is that you're measuring winding number.

Comment: @CyrylL. I encourage you to answer your question (so that it is no longer unanswered.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer proposed by Steve D.

By the homotopy axiom, the map $H(f):H_1(S^1) \rightarrow H_1(S^1)$ is the same for homotopic maps $g \simeq f$.

When $|a|<1$, we give the homotopy 
$$ H_t(z):= \frac{z-ta}{|z-ta|}.$$
So the degree of $f$ is equivalent to that of $g(z)=z$, which is $1$.

When $|a|>1$, we give the homotopy 
$$H_t(z):= \frac{tz-a}{|tz-a|}$$ 
so the degree of $f$ is equivalent to that of the constant map, which has degree $0$.